# Could not find a Coverage file! Searched for lcov.info, cov.xml, coverage.xml, jacoco.xml, coverage.cobertura.xml

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-code, code-coverage

I have installed Coverage gutter https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryanluker.vscode-coverage-gutters and .NET Core Test Explorer https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.dotnet-test-explorer

When I try to watch the test covered code, I got below alert message.
`Could not find a Coverage file! Searched for lcov.info, cov.xml, coverage.xml, jacoco.xml, coverage.cobertura.xml`

Do I need to create file named as lcov.info? If yes, where should I create (Path)?